# Can not import TensorFlow for Swift in Xcode Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, tensorflow, swift-for-tensorflow

I'm trying to use Swift for TensorFlow and have followed the directions found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md

When I go ahead and import TensorFlow as such within a Swift Playground file:

```
import TensorFlow
```

I get this error: "The active toolchain is not compatible with playgrounds. libswiftCore.dylib could not be loaded"

I was able to use Swift for TensorFlow within the REPL so I know it should work. Anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this issue?  It clearly works as shown in this demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=819&v=Yze693W4MaU

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest stable toolchain (e.g. v 0.6), install it, then go to Xcode > File > New > Project > Macos - Command Line Tools (instead of Playground). Additionally, the December 23, 2019 development toolchain—and beyond—should not require switching to the Legacy Build System. More information in this discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/swift/dveQVX_ysfw).

Answer (score 1):

Was running into this as well.  Answered in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org) - turns out you need to make sure you are creating a macOS playground and not an iOS playground.

Comment: Thank you!  I was indeed using an iOS playground, however switching to macOS does not seem to fix the issue. I followed the setup instructions from the github repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Usage.md Could the problem be occurring because I also added the toolchain to my path to use with command line tools as per these instructions: https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md ? My Xcode version is 9.3 and MacOS is 10.13.3

Comment: Double check that your toolchain settings are correct and then try creating a brand new macOS playground

Comment: Same issue for me. I've tried Xcode 9.4 and Xcode 10 with a couple of the different releases and none of them can import TensorFlow properly. Following instructions here made no difference. I'll report back if I can fix.

Comment: Dear @ian-do, have you found a solution to your problem? I am using XCode 11 and have installed TensorFlow through package. But still facing the issue :-( .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turns out is the playground type.

From the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org) reply:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm still running into this issue despite changing to macOS, see my comment to anayini

Answer (score 1):

As a synthesis of answers above and my own experience now with the latest May 8, 2020 builds and comments from the Google Group, I find:

SUCCESS

- Xcode Project Command-line (as @8bitmp3 answered above)
- Command-line swiftc (using the -O argument. Note this is the compiler)

FAILURE

- Xcode Playground macOS (as @ian-do originally asked)
- Command-line swift (and confirmed by Google Group. Note this is the interpreter)

For those interested in the command-line success (macOS 10.15.4), install the toolchain from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md), create the source code file inference.swift per this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Usage.md), and execute the following:

```sh
# Test this command. Expected outcome is your existing Xcode app as show below
$ xcrun -f swift
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

# Switch to the new TensorFlow toolchain you installed
# Mine was located at /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-tensorflow-RELEASE-0.9.xctoolchain/
# Open the Info.plist file, locate CFBundleIdentifier, and copy the string value
# Mine was com.google.swift.20200507
$ export TOOLCHAINS=com.google.swift.20200507

# Test the switch to your TensorFlow toolchain. Note the different result
$ xcrun -f swift
/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-tensorflow-RELEASE-0.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

# Compile your Swift for TensorFlow source code
$ cd <directory with .swift file>
$ swiftc -O -sdk `xcrun --show-sdk-path` inference.swift

# Run the program
$ ./inference 
[[0.68070436]]
```