# Cannot import tensorflow in Swift playground

Tags: swift, xcode, tensorflow, swift-playground, swift-for-tensorflow

I am an `iOS` developer and trying to learn `tensorflow`

for my `Xcode 11.2.1`. I tried [installing tensorflow using this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md)

I got the package in Xcode toolchain.

[image]

But after installation when I verified installation, it failed. Swift playground is giving error

> No such module 'TensorFlow'

I created a new SwiftPlayground for ***macOS***, still, no avail.

Later I again installed tensorflow through [command-line from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3) and it too was successful. 
[image]

This time I had created a normal swift file to verify installation, but this too failed.

There is an [existing old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081481/can-not-import-tensorflow-for-swift-in-xcode-playground) on same issue, but that has not been helpful to me. Can anyone help me knows solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your queries:

1. Swift Playgrounds are not yet supported (available in future) by S4TF toolchains.
2. You can only build app for macOS right now but support for other OSs will be available in future.
3. Before you run your Swift file via CMD you need to `export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/{swift-toolchain}/usr/bin/"${PATH}"` where you should replace `{swift-toolchain}` with your S4TF toolchain name (clicking tab will suggest you available toolchains on your system). Then running `swift test.swift` will be (hopefully) successful.

Note: S4TF is still in early stage of development & is ready for beginners and researchers to work with it. But I personally feel that if you're developing an app for iOS it's a little early. I hope Apple with announce this feature in WWDC either in 2020 or 2021.

I hope this was helpful!

-- Rahul Bhalley

Comment: Substitution to point 3: You can use [`swiftenv`](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv) as path setter for Swift language. It's pretty handy! Check this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/issues/360) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you, as an iOS developer, want to deploy a model into an iOS app without "leaving Xcode (almost)", you may be able to replicate what this developer did [here](http://static.brettkoonce.com/presentations/machine_learning_mobile_recap.pdf). The author of that PDF presented at a S4TF design meeting not long ago. You may have seen this in the Google Groups discussion.

A workaround for model saving for you could be: use Python interop > import Keras > ... > Save model as `.h5`. Then, perhaps, you could use Apple's Python-based `coremltools` [for Keras](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.keras.convert.html) to integrate the model—now in the `.mlmodel` format— into your iOS app. I haven't tested this yet.